# How do I get my page to display data that my functions process as they finish rather than when every function finishes

Tags: javascript

I have got 4 functions in my `doLoad()` function that scan the document for spans and manipulate the data in them. these functions are very big and take a lot of time. 12 seconds.

The problem is, although these functions are independent of eachother, none of their work is presented until all 4 have finished execting.

I want them to display the data as they finish excuting instead of displaying the data after all four have finish. How can I achieve that?

this is how my doLoad function looks like

```
function doLoad(){

 ...
 myFunction1();
 myFunction2();
 myFunction3();
 myFunction4();

}
```

Comment: what is in each of the functions? can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
function doLoad() {
  setTimeout(myFunction1,1);
  setTimeout(myFunction2,2);
  setTimeout(myFunction3,3);
  setTimeout(myFunction4,4);
}
```

By default, JS executes sequentially.

Comment: That didn't work. any ideas why it does this to begin with? if a function edits a span's contents shouldnt it be displayed as soon as that function finishes?

Comment: It's just how JavaScript works. It goes through line by line for the most part. So when you execute your function it goes through your function until it ends or finds a return; and then repeats for every line. One thing you could try doing is setTimeout() on various sections of your function that manipulate the dom.

Answer (score 0):

If they are **really** independent you can use

```
function doLoad(){
    ...
    setTimeout (myFunction1,5);
    setTimeout (myFunction2,5);
    setTimeout (myFunction3,5);
    setTimeout (myFunction4,5);
}
```